# How do i add a constraint in Oracle SQL to limit a value?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i set a column in oracle to not accept numbers above 10000 and below 0?

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col check (col >= 0 and col <= 10000);
```

This will prevent inserting or updating any values in the column that are not in the specified range.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked !!!!!!!

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing? In the same way i can validate an email address before its inserted?

Comment: @NikosL24 . . . You can validate any column with a `check` constraint.  For an email, you would probably use a regular expression.

Comment: I've been searching about that.... how can you do a check before the INSERT so it displays an error ?

Comment: @NikosL24 . . . That is what a `check` constraint does.